# Ito's formula and sin(Brownian motion)

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, expected-value

I would like to compute:
$d(e^{\frac12t}sinB_t)$

using the integration by parts of Ito I come up with the following:$$\frac12e^{\frac12t}sinB_tdt +e^{\frac12t}cosB_tdB_t + 0$$ however I the solution should be only $e^{\frac12t}cosB_tdB_t$. where is the mistake?

moreover what is the result of $E[e^{\frac12t}sinB_t]$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050451/which-function-makes-ft-sinwt-a-martingale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct formula in this case is
$$
d f(B_t,t)=f_1(B_t,t)\,dB_t+f_2(B_t,t)\,dt+\frac{1}{2}f_{11}(B_t,t)\,d[B_t].
$$
Applying this to $f(x,t)=e^{t/2}\sin(x)$, one gets
\begin{align}\label{1}\tag{1}
df(B_t,t)&=e^{t/2}\cos(B_t)\,dB_t+\frac{1}{2}e^{t/2}\sin(B_t)\,dt-\frac{1}{2}e^{t/2}\sin(B_t)\,dt \\
&=e^{t/2}\cos(B_t)\,dB_t.
\end{align}
It follows that $\mathsf{E}f(B_t,t)=0$ ($\because$ the RHS of $\eqref{1}$ is a martingale starting at $0$).

Comment: you see that it is a martingale because there is no dt component, right?

Comment: Yes, there is no drift component and a stochastic integral w.r.t. a BM is a martingale.

Comment: I would add: is a martingale if the integrand is in $\lambda ^2$. I should check that $E[\int_0^\infty e^scos(B_s)^2ds]< \infty$. Right? and actually it seems to me that it is not, or am I wrong?

Comment: It suffices that $\mathsf{E} \int_0^T e^s \cos^2(B_s)\,ds<\infty$ for all $T$; see Corollary 3.2.6 [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=VgQDWyihxKYC&pg=PA162&dq=oksendal+stochastic+differential+equations+Corollary3.2.6&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjpPWt6czmAhWPUMAKHeN6AS8Q6AEIMzAB#v=onepage&q=corollary%203.2.6&f=false).

Comment: so it depend on the domain of the stochastic integral? Namely if $\int_0^\infty f(t ,w )dB_t$ then it has to hold that $E\int_0^\infty f(t,w) dt < \infty$; while if $\int_0^Tf(t ,w )dB_t$ Then is sufficient $E \int_0^T f(t,w) dt< \infty$ for all T?

Comment: $\int_0^\infty f(t.\omega)\,d B_t$ is not a process (even if it exists) and so it is meaningless to talk about its martingale properties.

Comment: and therefore when I have to check the condition that $E[\int_0^\infty f(t, w )dt ]< \infty$?

Comment: Probably when you want to show that the stochastic integral $\int_0^\infty f(t,\omega)\,dB_t$ exists. Also $\int_0^\infty \mathsf{E}[f(t,\omega)]^2\, dt<\infty$ is a sufficient condition for $\int_0^t f(t,\omega)\,dB_t$ to be a martingale.

Comment: it imply the existence of the stochastic integral because if the E[ ]$<\infty$ then it mean that also $\int_0^\infty f()^2dt < \infty$ namely that the quadratic variation is finite, and this imply finite stochastic integral? But then why I need also that the E[$\int_0^\infty f()^2dt $] is finite?

Comment: I am not sure that I follow your questions. Anyway, you don't need that condition for the martingale property of the integral in $(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

You are computing $d(\sin B_t)$ like if it was a differentiable function.

If we apply Ito's formula with the function $f(x)= \sin x,$ we get 
$$d(\sin B_t) = \cos B_t dB_t - \frac{1}{2} \sin B_t dt.$$
Now applying the integration by parts formula, you will get the result
\begin{align*}
d(e^ {\frac{1}{2}t} \sin B_t) &= e^{\frac{1}{2}t} d(\sin B_t) + \frac{1}{2}e^ {\frac{1}{2}t} \sin B_t dt \\
&= ...
\end{align*}

For the other question, you can use the fact that $B_t \sim N(0, \sqrt{t})$ in conjunction with this: [Compute $E(\sin X)$ if $X$ is normally distributed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2134801/compute-e-sin-x-if-x-is-normally-distributed)